# Error: undefined control sequence

Tags: math-mode, formatting

I have a minor error in the below code, although it gets compiled without error, but it complains with:

```
Error: undefined control sequence
```

I want to get

`child(V)={ u ∈ N(v) | d(root,u)=d(root,v)+1 }`

as output

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multirow
\usepackage{hhline}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hhline

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\begin{document}

$$\child(V)=\{ u \in N(v) | d(root,u)=d(root,v)+1  \}$$


\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no `\child` operator defined by default.

Comment: how can i write for `child(V)={ u ∈ N(v) | d(root,u)=d(root,v)+1 }`

Comment: Depending on what you want it to look like - but `\mathrm{child}(V) = \{ u \in N(v) ~|~ d(\mathrm{root}, u) = d(\mathrm{root}, v) + 1 \}` should do it for example.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare `\child` as a math operator, but also use `\mathrm` for `root` Never use math italic for words, it separates the letters to make it look like a product of variables. Also use `\[` never `$$` in LaTeX.

```
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multirow
\usepackage{hhline}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hhline

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\DeclareMathOperator\child{child}
\begin{document}

\[
\child(V)=\{ u \in N(v) | d(\mathrm{root},u)=d(\mathrm{root},v)+1  \}
\]


\end{document}
```